# Sending multiple groups of checkboxes to PHP via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have checked various SO questions

1. [How to send a checkbox group via ajax in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298777/how-to-send-a-checkbox-group-via-ajax-in-jquery)
2. [serializing checkboxes in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389050/serializing-checkboxes-in-jquery)

But none of these send more than one set of checkboxes.

I have a form with a series of checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="2"/>
...
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="2"/>
...
```

There are also some other non checkboxes on the form.

I send this to php via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/filter',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { filter: $(self.form).serializeArray()},
    dataType: 'JSON'
});
```

I then need to get each set of checkbox values in PHP. So I output the post:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 

array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'color[]' (length=7)
  'value' => string '4' (length=1)
1 => 
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'color[]' (length=7)
  'value' => string '6' (length=1)
2 => 
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'length[]' (length=8)
  'value' => string '3' (length=1)
3 => 
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'length[]' (length=8)
  'value' => string '5' (length=1)
```

But how can I get each set of values? I want a var with all colors, and a var with all sizes.

Just to clarify - I'm looking for a way in PHP to get the colors into an array and another array for lenths.

Something like:

```
$_POST['filter']['color'];
```

Comment: The code looks alright!!!

Comment: `$(self.form).serializeArray()` looks good and it should do it. Have you checked the output in console ?

Comment: I believe you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9298836/3282633) one too

Comment: The JS code is fine, just how do I get what I want in PHP? I want something like $colors = $_POST['filter'['color']]];

Comment: I don't think it's totally clear what you want to do. Can you give us an example rather than just a description of what you want?

Comment: Read the question - But how can I get each set of values? I want a var with all colors, and a var with all sizes.

Comment: @panthro: show us the query string sent in XHR POST request body (get it from Firebug or so)

Comment: what does the complete $_POST give you?

Comment: Query string: filter%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=color%5B%5D&filter%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=2&filter%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=color%5B%5D&filter%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=3&filter%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=color%5B%5D&filter%5B2%5D%5Bvalue%5D=6&filter%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=length%5B%5D&filter%5B3%5D%5Bvalue%5D=3&filter%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=length%5B%5D&filter%5B4%5D%5Bvalue%5D=4

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com complete post is given above in question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the result already been a array of checked value when send to php?
If it is, then you need to pre-process it:

```
var result = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="color[]"]').each(function(_, ele) {
    if ($(ele).prop('checked')) {
       result.push($(ele).attr('value'));
      }
});
```

Hope its what you want.

Comment: Is there not an easier way to do this with serialize.

Comment: To my knowledge, you have to either handle it in php use a forloop to check each item's name and get its value to correct place, or you have to form the result in javascript before send it, sorry I'm not sure there's a more elegant way to solve it.

Comment: I don't have php handy, but maybe you could try use .serialize() instead of .serializeArray(), then use $_POST['filter']['color'] in PHP to see if you get what you expect? Nevermind if you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of PHP code that will convert your `$_POST` to a new array called `$filter`

```
$filter = array();
foreach ($_POST as $checkbox) {
    if (substr($checkbox['name'],-2) == '[]') {
        $name = substr($checkbox['name'],0,-2);
        if (!array_key_exists($name,$filter)){
            $filter[$name] = array();
        }
        array_push($filter[$name],$checkbox['value']);
    }
}
print_r($filter);
```

What it does is:

1. It checks if `name` ends with `[]` if that's the case it is assumed to be a checkbox, if not it's ignored.
2. It will generate a new array in `$filter` that contains an array for each checkbox group

So `$filter` to your example `$_POST` will look like this:

```
Array ( 
  ['color'] => Array ( 
    [0] => 4 
    [1] => 6 
  ) 
  ['length'] => Array ( 
    [0] => 3 
    [1] => 5 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$colors = $_POST['filter']['color'];

print_r($colors);
?>
```

Comment: This is not very helpful. Please add some color around the code. Explain what you are doing.