# How to send a PHP array via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

On my signup page people can sign up for my website by filling in some inputs ad checkboxes. It's basically a form that sends the data to a PHP page with ajax which then puts it in the database.

The javascript gets the values from the form like this for example

```
var w = _("website").value;
var bio = _("bio").value;
```

and then sends it like this `ajax.send("w="+w+"&bio="+bio);` This is working as it should, but I want to add something.

Now I have a number of checkboxes that I want to get in an array that gets posted in one variable via ajax. So in my form I have this piece of PHP:

```
$licensessql = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM licenses");
while($licenserecord = mysqli_fetch_assoc($licensessql)) {
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$licenserecord["license"].'" name="licenses[]" id="'.$licenserecord["license"].'"><label for="'.$licenserecord["license"].'">'.$licenserecord["license"].'</label><br>';
}
```

Using pure PHP this would work and put all the values from the checkboxes in an array licences[], but I have no idea how to achieve this using ajax. If I have 5 checkboxes, I want the javascript var to have for example the value 'value1,value2,value3' and have that posted to PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend using form serialization as posted in other answers.

To answer your actual question: `"If I have 5 checkboxes, I want the javascript var to have for example the value 'value1,value2,value3' and have that posted to PHP."`

Here's a fully working example (using 3 checkboxes) which will produce a javascript variable which you can use to pass to your AJAX post method for PHP to process.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o5q04vf0/

Code Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnTest').click(function() {
    var checkBoxValues = $("[name=licenses\\[\\]]").map(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        return this.value;
      }
    }).get().join();

    alert(checkBoxValues);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="0" name="licenses[]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="licenses[]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="licenses[]" />
<button id="btnTest">Submit</button>
```

This will help you guide in the right direction but do consider switching your approach in passing data through AJAX like other members suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST and serialize the array as data

```js
  $data = $('form').serialize();
    $.post( "ajax/test.html", function($data) {
      $( ".result" ).html( data );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

in PHP you use `$_POST['attributeName']` to read the value

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I only want this value to be serialized so this is what I have now for the value of the array: `var licenses = $('input[name="licenses"]').serializeArray();`This is what gets posted to the database. Because I have other checkboxes as well outside the array, I needed to specify the name.But this is what gets posted to the database now instead of the real values: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389050/serializing-checkboxes-in-jquery I think this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can send all form data with `serializeArray` function.
`Serialize` use for GET, and `serializeArray` is useful for POST.

```
$('#btn-send').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url-to-data-send',
        method: 'post',
        data: $(this).closest('form').serializeArray(); <--- send form data
    }).done(function(response) {
        alert('form sent');
    })
});
```

or you can specify what you want to send definetely

```
var data = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
    console.log(data);
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wx3rodmr/)

**** EDIT ****

This does what you want I guess

```
var arr = [];
$.map( $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="chck[]"]:checked'), function( n, i ) {
     arr.push({ name: $(n).attr('name'), value: $(n).val()});
});
console.log(arr);
```

[FIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/wx3rodmr/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I only want this value to be serialized so this is what I have now for the value of the array: `var licenses = $('input[name="licenses"]').serializeArray();`This is what gets posted to the database. Because I have other checkboxes as well outside the array, I needed to specify the name.But this is what gets posted to the database now instead of the real values: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ...

Comment: @SenneVandenputte I updated my answer, check if help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

You need Serialize function! Here is an exaple how you may use it:

HTML:

```
<form id="yourOrderFormId" method="post">
<input type="checkbox"/><input type="text"/>
<input type="checkbox"/><input type="text"/>
<button id="yourButtonId">Send</button>
</form>
```

jQuery Ajax:

```
<script>
    $('#yourButtonId').click(function(e) {

       var yourData = $("#yourOrderFormId").serialize(); 

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/yourUrl',
            data: yourData,
            dataType: 'html',
           success:success: function (result) {
           alert("Your message sent!");
           }
    });
```

Or use with serializeArray();

```
console.log($('form').serializeArray());
```

Here :[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/zZh7t/1/)

Hope it helps;)

Comment: I only want the values of my array to be serialized, the rest has to be send through javascript variables because of checking them for errors. How can I only serialize the array with checkboxes that have the name "Licenses"?

Comment: @SenneVandenputte try this method: if you want to serialize only checkboxes use this: var yourData = $("yourCheckboxId").val() ; insted of  var yourData = $("#yourOrderFormId").serialize();

Comment: I think it is working now, but in my database I see now [object Object],[object Object] instead of the checkbox values..

Comment: @SenneVandenputte I think, if you send your data with this method it will be fine : var yourData = $("#yourOrderFormId").serialize();   ps. if it helps pls, check mark for my solution.Thanx ;)

Comment: I just used your method and when I use `var licenses = $('input[name="licenses"]').val();` it sends it correctly, but only the first value. Not the array. I feel like it's almost working but nog completely yet

Comment: @SenneVandenputte What are you geting  error if you are using var yourData = $("#yourOrderFormId").serialize() ? , Serialize sends array of objects how you want

Comment: I can absolutely not serialize all my form data because I use the variables to check for certain things. Only the checkboxes can be serialized so I need a way to get the array from the checkboxes in my variable..

Comment: @SenneVandenputte I finded something :) try this:var licenses = $('input[name="licenses"]').serializeArray();

Comment: This always returns the correct amount of checked boxes but without a value.. This is what is posted to the database: [object Object],[object Object] so no correct values..

Comment: @SenneVandenputte Here is defination: "The serializeArray() method creates an array of objects (name and value) by serializing form values." Are you tried to select checkbox input with Id?  for ex something like this:  $("#yourCheckboxId").serializeArray(); http://jsfiddle.net/zZh7t/1/